# Anonymous Functions, "Parse Issue: Expected Expression"

Tags: c++, anonymous-function

I'm getting the titular error, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to resolve it. I've scoured the internet a fair bit, but for the most part I can't find anything that pertains directly to, or solves, the problem I'm having, and all the information I read about anonymous classes, seems to agree with the code I wrote.

The essence of what I'm trying to do is; I have a struct, and I want that struct to contain a function pointer. What I'm having trouble with is when I define an instance of the struct, I'm trying to create and pass an anonymous function to the struct. But it's giving me a compile error.

Anyways, here are the **details of the actual problem**, the error occurs on this line,

```
[&](int x) { this->moveLeft(); };
```

It says "Parse Issue: Expected expression" and points to the ']'

of the following code

```
Combatant::CharacterData Combatant::characters = {
    /*Name      */"SomeName",
    /*Folder    */"SomeFolder",
    /*Offense   */1.0f,
    /*Defense   */1.0f,
    /*Combos    */{
        {KeyMemory(KeyMemory::MOVE_LEFT, KeyMemory::JUMP),
            [&](int x) { this->moveLeft(); };
        },
        {KeyMemory(KeyMemory::MOVE_LEFT, KeyMemory::JUMP),
            [&](int x) { this->moveLeft(); };
        }
    }
}
```

The CharacterData struct is defined by this code:

```
    struct Combo {
        KeyMemory controls;
        void (*execute)(int);
    };

    struct CharacterData {
        std::string name;
        std::string folder;
        float offense;
        float defense;
        Combo comboList[5];
    };
```

Any help, would be much appreciated. ^_^

Comment: Are you coming from JavaScript?

Comment: I see, your code reminded me of JavaScript. Anyways, lambdas are nice and clean syntax for functors and function pointers are incompatible with them, if you want to store a lambda, use `std::function<void(int)> myFunc = [&](int x) { this->moveLeft();};`.

Comment: @Jesse @StilesCrisis 
Hmm, so I changed it to use std::function instead, but I am encountering the same problem. Same error, same place. The changes that I made are: 
`void (*execute)(int);`
became
`std::function<void(Combatant*)> execute;`

and

`[&](int x) { this->moveLeft(); };`
became
`[](Combatant* user) { user->moveLeft(); };`

Comment: Are you sure lambda expressions are available and enabled in your compiler?? Otherwise I'm a bit stumped at the moment...

Comment: Right, I looked into it, and yes, apparently Clang does not yet support lambda functions. I'll find a work around. Thanks a lot for the help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that Clang, which is the compiler used by Xcode/Apple doesn't yet support lambda functions. From what I read however the feature is coming in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use a `std::function<void(int)>` to hold your lambda. (Particularly since you are using `[&]`).

Also, I'm not sure `[&]` actually makes sense in a global context. Maybe you should be passing in the object to call `moveLeft` on, and using `[]`. Also, that change might let you use your simple function pointer instead of a `std::function`.

Comment: what is [&]?  Is this in one of the new specs?

Comment: Yeah, I was initially using [](Combatant user){}, but I was fiddling around with the parameters to try and see if I could figure out the problem. Unfortunately those didn't work either, I will try std::function though.

Comment: Michael, it's a C++11 lambda expression.